# aligning and styling input type="file" with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue formating a button and input type="file" using bootstrap.

Depending on what arrangement, trying similar solution found on SE, and using what I think should work, I just can't seem to style a file selector with a submit button.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="file" name="file" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </span>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The file input is not stylized to a primary button color, and it is off center.  I can get the file input to be the correct style, but then the button is not correct (smaller, but against the input="file").

How can I fix the input="file" to look correctly?
if it makes any difference, I'm using the free flat-ui

[image: bad bootstrap]

Comment: hide the actual input and play around by using different control with css

Comment: @jonju has the right idea. You may want to look into [Cory LaViska article](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3). He nailed it.